# react-native-maps how to tell if user location is off of the visible map

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

is there a way to tell the current visibile boundaries of the react-native-maps. I want to know when the user isn't visible on the maps anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use permission package. React-native-maps doesn't provide permission. I used https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-permissions many times. It works well.

```
Permissions.request('location').then(response => {
    // Returns once the user has chosen to 'allow' or to 'not allow' access      
    // Response is one of: 'authorized', 'denied', 'restricted', or 'undetermined'      
    this.setState({ locationPermission: response })      
})
```

Comment: how can i use this to tell when the user is out of focus on react native maps?